# How can I store the shareable data in sealed class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement UiState class with sealed class(I am using Jetpack Compose + ViewModel)

The screen should have mutable data in all the state once result is initialized.

So, I created sealed class like this.

```
sealed class ResultUiState {
    private lateinit var result: ResultData

    object Prepping : ResultUiState()
    object Loading : ResultUiState()
    object Idle : ResultUiState()

    data class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int): ResultUiState() {
        init {
            result = this
        }
    }

    fun getResultData() = result
}
```

I checked ResultData is created. But if I access like `resultUiState.result` it is not initialized.

As far as I know, ResultUiState can't be initiated because it is just like class containers. I think that's the reason why it's not working.

I don't want to create other classes because it doesn't look clean and do all the thing in that sealed class. How can I solve this issue?

I tested in Kotlin Playground and it works as I expected.

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference

sealed class ResultUiState {
    lateinit var result: ResultData

    object Prepping : ResultUiState()
    object Loading : ResultUiState()
    object Idle : ResultUiState()

    data class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int): ResultUiState() {
        init {
            result = this
        }
    }

    fun getResultData() = result
}

fun main() {
    var resultUiState : ResultUiState = ResultUiState.Prepping
    println("resultUiState: $resultUiState")
    resultUiState = ResultUiState.Idle
    println("resultUiState: $resultUiState")
    resultUiState = ResultUiState.ResultData("Hello", 7)
    println("resultUiState: $resultUiState")
    println("resultUiState: $resultUiState, result: ${resultUiState.getResultData()}")
    resultUiState = ResultUiState.Loading
    println("resultUiState: $resultUiState, result: ${resultUiState.getResultData()}")
}

// Result
resultUiState: ResultUiState$Prepping@49c2faae
resultUiState: ResultUiState$Idle@5197848c
resultUiState: ResultData(a=Hello, b=7)
resultUiState: ResultData(a=Hello, b=7), result: ResultData(a=Hello, b=7)
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property result has not been initialized
 at ResultUiState.getResult (File.kt:4) 
 at ResultUiState.getResultData (File.kt:16) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:28)
```

What I'd like to achieve is, Think about Kiosk. There are menus and price list. The data shouldn't be changed in Loading, Error, etc. But only updates whenever it's Success state.

Comment: Can you let us know more about what you are trying to achieve?  Your code will not even compile

Comment: `result = this` doesn’t make any sense. Why would a class need to hold a reference to itself in a property? Why is only one of the children of the sealed class using this property? Why is there a useless getter function that simply passes through to a property?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi, I updated the code and it compiles.

Comment: @Tenfour04 well, I wanted it to be `private lateinit var result: ResultData` so that it initialize only once. fixed the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example of the **Sealed** class I use for API calls using a retrofit. You can modify sealed class parameters according to your need.

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val errorCode: Int? = 0,
    val errorBody: ResponseBody? = null
) {
    class Ideal<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(data: T? = null, message: String, errorCode: Int?, errorBody: ResponseBody?) :
        Resource<T>(data, message, errorCode, errorBody)
}
```

Observing API Response in Fragment or Activity like this

```
private fun observeAPIResponse(response: Resource<MY API DATA CLASS>) {
    when (response) {
        is Resource.Ideal -> {}
        is Resource.Loading -> {
            
        }
        is Resource.Success -> {
            
        }
        is Resource.Error -> {
   
        }
}
```

In ViewModel class I am setting value to Resource Class like below.

```
val liveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<MY API DATA CLASS>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getApiResponseList() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        liveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            if (isNetworkAvailable(app)) {
                val apiResult = myusecase.execute()
                liveData.postValue(apiResult)
            } else {
                liveData.postValue(Resource.Error(null, “No Internet Connection”, 1009, null))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            liveData.postValue(Resource.Error(null,e.message.toString(),null,null))
        }
    }
```

You can use **postValue** method to set value to **Resource(Sealed)** class

Comment: I'm sorry to say this is a very poor sealed class example since it doesn’t use the main feature of a sealed class—the children don’t have to all be the same class. You’ve put all the properties in the superclass as nullables. For example it doesn’t make sense that Success has an `errorCode` property or that Error has a `data` property, and it’s a shame that the Success class has nullable `data` and the Error class has nullable `message`. This is no better than an enum and a single class.

Comment: Here’s a sensible version of this sealed class hierarchy. It’s a sealed interface for simplicity. The non-Success classes don’t use generics since they don’t carry data, making them easier to use. Data and error message properties are non-nullable so you don’t have to needlessly deal with nullability for things when they are never null. Loading and Ideal are objects so you don’t have to instantiate multiple instances of them—they are stateless so that would be pointless. https://pl.kotl.in/sRqRfvCni

Comment: Hello, @Tenfour04 Thanks for your suggestions. I really appreciated it. I was using the same sealed class that you provided in the link. But due to our backend API structure, I was changing sealed classes based on requirements. But I will change my sealed class based on your suggestion. Thanks. 

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. But for me, Loading, Idle, etc. don't really need to know the data. I don't want to pass the same data to all the classes because it looks useless because only Success class matters(in my code ResultData) the UI data. Think about Kiosk. There are menus and price list. The data shouldn't be changed in Loading, Error, etc. But only updates whenever it's Success state.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some misconceptions about classes in general here.

To start with, you've defined `sealed class ResultUiState` with a `lateinit` property `result`. That means each instance of `ResultUiState` you create will have its own instance of that property, i.e. `Prepping`, `Loading` and `Idle` are all instances of `ResultUiState` with their own `result` instance variables.

Because that property is `lateinit`, you're not actually assigning anything to it. Defining the `ResultData` class inside `ResultUiState` doesn't actually *create an instance of it*, so its `init` block will only run when you actually construct a `ResultData` object.

But because `result` is an *instance variable*, `ResultData` can't assign anything to it - it's just a class that happens to be nested inside the `ResultUiState` class, it's not related to any *specific instance* of that class. To do that, you'd have to make it an `inner` class (which precludes it being a `data class`):

```
inner class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int) {
    init {
        result = this
    }
}
```

*Now* every instance of `ResultData` belongs to a specific instance of `ResultUiState`, so it can access that `result` instance variable. You still need to actually create that instance though, calling its constructor through the parent instance:

```
ResultUiState.Prepping.ResultData("wow", 123)
println(ResultUiState.Prepping.result.a)

>> wow
```

Which isn't really very useful or intuitive, so you probably want to do something else? But hopefully that explains why it wasn't working the way you hoped.

---

Generally speaking, the way you'd use sealed classes like this is to use `object`s for fixed states with no data, and *class instances* (e.g. a `data class`) for states that *do* have data. Then you'd just supply that data, if required, through the constructor.

```
sealed class ResultUiState {
    object Prepping : ResultUiState()
    object Loading : ResultUiState()
    data class Loaded(val result: ResultData) : ResultUiState()

    // this doesn't need to be "inner" because it's purely a data object, it doesn't
    // have any knowledge of ResultUiState - it's just convenient to nest it
    // so it's referenced as ResultUiState.ResultData, makes it clear what it is!
    data class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int)
    // NOTE: this is NOT a ResultUiState (it doesn't extend that class)
    // so it's not a member of the sealed class hierarchy - it's not one of
    // your states. It's just located here for organisation/naming purposes
}
```

Because `Prepping` has no data related to the state, you can just reuse a singleton `object` because it's always the same. Whereas `Loaded` actually contains some data, so you need separate instances of that state, and you pass the data in when constructing it. This is why it's a good fit for a data class!

The nice thing about sealed classes is you can mix and match different classes and objects like this - `Loaded` is the only one with a `result` property, but by doing an `is` check or matching the type with a `when` block, when you determine your `ResultUiState` is a `Loaded` you can just access `result` directly (because of smart casting). And all the states that don't *need* a `result` don't have one. Makes things really neat and consistent, and lets you define your data very specifically and make sure it's always valid.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect code, I updated. So, best way is taking `ResultData` ouf of the sealed class and keep it seperatly?

Comment: @c-an no you can keep it inside like in my example, and like I said I prefer organising it like that if `ResultData` is specific to `ResultUiState` - nesting it so you access it as `ResultUiState.ResultData` makes it clear what it is and what it belongs to, and prevents confusion with other unrelated classes called `ResultData`.

Comment: I can keep ResultData class but, in compose, it would be passed like 'resultUiState: ResultUiState' as parameter. And I cannot access like resultUiState. But I need to check the type like `val a: String = if(resultUiState is ResultData) (resultUiState as ResultData).a`. And when the state changes to Loading, Prepping, then it will be empty.  And display shows nothing. Is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: @c-an I don't know anything about Compose, sorry - but `ResultData` is just nested inside `ResultUiState` for organisation, it's not a subclass of `ResultUiState`. There's no `: ResultUiState()` in the class declaration, see? So what you'd actually check is if your `ResultUiState` is a `Loaded`, in which case it has a `result` property you can access. Other states which don't need to contain that data don't have it. So you'd handle displaying things depending on what subtype of `ResultUiState` you got - if you get a `Prepping`, you show something else like a loading spinner, etc

Comment: ResultData inherits ResultUiState. Please check the edited code. It's not only for Compose but these days, XML also state with sealed classes, So, it won't make so much difference.

Comment: @c-an are you sure `ResultData` should inherit from `ResultUiState`? That implies that "result data" is *one of your states*, but `ResultUiState` also *has a `ResultData` property* which implies that it's just data *associated* with some or all states. (Right now it's *all* states since `result` is `lateinit` instead of *nullable*, so a `ResultData` value is supposed to exist there). There are a lot of signs that your design is wrong here, if you see what I mean. The example I gave has a set of states (objects and classes) and `ResultData` is just a specific set of data some states might have

Comment: @c-an easiest way to answer here is just to ask exactly what you're going for - what UI states do you need? What states can your UI be in? Is it just *prepping*, *loading* and *idle*? And which states need a `ResultData` data object associated with them? Which ones don't need to provide that data at all?

Comment: yes, ResultData can be state like `data class Success(val data: Data) : ResultUiState()`. So, once it gets data onSuccess. then, I want to keep the data even in other States. And I know the design is wrong, but I explained what I wanted to do. That's why I asked here. As I explained already, Think about kiosk, it shows the list of products and the price info, cart info while Loading and Idle, once it fetches the data.

Comment: @c-an but that's not `ResultData` **as a state**, that's a state called `Success` that **has** a `ResultData` as part of its data, no? `ResultData` is a collection of values associated with specific states, but not others. It would be the same as giving `Success` a `String` and an `Int` property, you've just created a (reusable) class called `ResultData` that represents the data contained in those two values. Does `Idle` need to hold that data as well? If not, it shouldn't have a property for it, which is why it shouldn't be a property in the `ResultUiState` superclass, only where it's used

Comment: It's up to you what you want to do, but the way you're doing things is making it more complicated, because instead of just saying "`Idle` has no data associated with it, it's just a simple state. `Success` has a `ResultData` property with some info about the state" you're making it so *everything* has a `ResultData`, even where it's not used. That's forcing you into this situation where you need to initialise the property in some cases and not others, instead of it just either being part of the state's constructor or not. But if you *are* doing it this way, make `result` nullable, not lateinit

Comment: Well, forget about the naming. I used `ResultData` as one of `Success` State. So, it can be `Success(val result: ResultData) : ResultUiState`. The problem is 'How I can share the data that received once at the Success state afterwards even in other states'. Well, I guess taking the data out from the UiState class is the best.. and just hold it in the ViewModel.

Comment: @c-an if you want a global value that all states can access, you could create a `companion object` inside `ResultUiData` and put a property in there - all instances of that class will share it. But I'd argue, from what you've said, that this data isn't actually related to the other states at all, and it's only related to one specific instance of `Success`. If you just want some kind of "last result" value, then yeah I think storing the `result` from the last `Success` that you received in the View Model is probably a good way to do it. Then anything that needs that cached data can access it

Comment: Not a global value. but for a screen. `companion object` is not a good option. Yeah, I just took it out of out sealed class and store it in the ViewModel. I think I should think about what is state. I thought all the data can be state.

Comment: @c-an I don't want to turn this into a massive comment thread - but there might be a little confusion here. With this sealed class stuff we're talking about *states* as in a *state machine* - a fixed set of possible states you can be in. Here it can be *idle*, *prepping*, *loading* or *succeeded* (I'd say *completed* would be better, might be a success or failure). You use the sealed class to define all the possible states, and then you handle them all. Some states might have other data associated with them (e.g. a result value, or an error message) and some might have no data (e.g. *idle*)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the basics of a sealed class and how it is really just like an abstract class. Strip away `sealed` and the way you are nesting your classes, and this is like what you're doing:

```
abstract class ResultBase {
    lateinit var data: ResultData
}

data class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int): ResultBase() {
    init {
        data = this
    }
}

class Loaded: ResultBase()
```

Do you see the confusion you have yet? `data` is a property in every subclass of the abstract class. `Loading` has a property `data` because it is a subclass of `ResultBase`. `ResultBase` also has a property `data` that it is assigning itself to, which is completely pointless.

If you still don't see it, strip away the base class, and this is what your classes look like:

```
data class ResultData(val a: String, val b: Int) {
    var data: ResultData = this
}

class Loaded: ResultBase {
    lateinit var data: ResultData
}
```

It makes no sense at all. Every one of the children of your sealed class is carrying around a useless property. For `ResultData`, it's useless because it just references itself. For the rest of them, you never assign anything to it.

I think cactustictacs figured out what you're actually attempting to do and has the right solution.